# Visual Studio Code getting question marks instead of an equal sign

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I'm getting question marks in IntelliSense instead of equal signs. Can you help me please?

[image]

Comment: Maybe the question marks mean that the attributes are optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TypeScript, which Visual Studio Code uses for indexing and IntelliSense, question marks in properties mean that they are optional. In that case, you don't explicitly *need* to specify them.

For example, `type?` in IntelliSense would mean you *can* specify the `type` attribute if you want, but you don't actually *need* to.

This is normal, and you need to put the equal signs in yourself.